# after pressing verification link ... nothing happens in Django .. user still unverified

Tags: django, smtp

Views.py(name of app: userprofileinfo)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from userprofileinfo.forms import UserForm
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt,csrf_protect
from django.views import View
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text, DjangoUnicodeDecodeError
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode, urlsafe_base64_encode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .utils import account_activation_token
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import auth



@login_required
def special(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("You are logged in, Nice!")


@login_required
def userlogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('careforallapp:base'))


def register(request):
    registered = False




    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            email = UserForm('email')
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            email_body = {
                    'user': user,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            }

            link = reverse('userprofileinfo:activate', kwargs={
                               'uidb64': email_body['uid'], 'token': email_body['token']})

            email_subject = 'Activate your account'

            activate_url = 'http://'+current_site.domain+link
            
            send_mail(
                    email_subject,
                    'Hi '+user.username + ', Please the link below to activate your account \n'+activate_url,
                    'settings.EMAIL_HOST',
                    [user.email],
                    fail_silently=False
            )

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('careforallapp:base'))
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()


    return render(request,'userprofileinfo/registration.html',
                           {'user_form':user_form,
                           'registered':registered})

class VerificationView(View):
    def get(self, request, uidb64, token):
        try:
            id = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=id)

            if not account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
                return redirect('login'+'?message='+'User already activated')

            if user.is_active:
                return redirect('login')
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Account activated successfully')
            return redirect('login')

        except Exception as ex:
            pass

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('userprofileinfo:userlogin'))

def userlogin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('careforallapp:base'))

            else:
                return HttpResponse("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed!")
            print("Username: {} and password: {}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("invalid login details")
    else:
        return render(request, 'userprofileinfo/login.html', {})
```

.env

```
export EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=*******
export EMAIL_HOST_USER = careall249@gmail.com
export EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from .views import VerificationView
from userprofileinfo import views

app_name = 'userprofileinfo'

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^login/', views.userlogin, name='userlogin'),
     url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),
     url(r'^logout/', views.userlogout, name='userlogout'),
     url(r'^special/', views.special, name='special'),
     path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>', VerificationView.as_view(), name='activate'),
]
```

Can someone go through the code. Login page, registration page all working fine but verification link is not working, when user register, he gets the link on his Gmail but when he presses the link for verify nothing happens. User not get active. Can somebody go through it and find the error.

Comment: What happens when the link is clicked? How the URL is being filled?
In your `VerificationView` you're bypassing exceptions, so you're not getting any errors. Throw the exception, so you can see better what's happening.

Comment: Okay sir, I give it a try.

Comment: No errors. I had changed the exception  `except Exception as ex: print("something went wrong")` . But still no errors.